Is it possible or practical to just solve integer optimization problem by penalizing?
I am an engineer who is currently working in network optimization problem. I have finised my master degree a long time ago. During my studies I have learnt about the penalty technique to turn a constrained optimization problem into an unconstrained ones and solve it. At that time, I was just studied to have enough credit.
But latter on, my work requires me to deal with 0-1 integer optimization problem. Out of curiousity, I just want to know why people invent so many branch and bound, branch and cut method to solve this special optimization problem.
At first glance, it seems to me that I could just solve these 0-1  optimization problem by penalizing.
I have conduct an investigation of my own using wikipedia and it said here that
"The advantage of the penalty method is that, once we have a penalized objective with no constraints, we can use any unconstrained optimization method to solve it. The disadvantage is that, as the penalty coefficient p grows, the unconstrained problem becomes ill-conditioned - the coefficients are very large, and this may cause numeric errors and slow convergence of the unconstrained minimization"
However, I am not sure if this is the compelling reason to avoid penalization or not. Therefore, my question is "Is it possible or practical to just solve integer optimization problem by penalizing ?"
Please help me with this, thank you for your enthusiasm !

Penalizing works when the function is smooth. 0-1 is discrete

What penalty do you have in mind?

Last time I study it the professor just teach interior penalty and exterior penalty but I am willing to learn about other

I assume that you mean moving all functional constraints into the objective function with penalties while retaining the integrality restriction on the $n$ binary variables. You can do that, but you still will need some sort of branch-and-bound solver to avoid having to enumerate all $2^n$ possible solutions.
You may also need to solve the problem repeatedly, because choosing the penalty function and coefficients can be tricky. You are basically describing Lagrangian relaxation. The penalties need to be big enough to make any "superoptimal" solution unattractive while not being so big that they create numerical issues, and they need to avoid creating rewards for slack in the constraints (which can make a suboptimal solution look attractive). So you may need to solve, check for violations, adjust penalties and solve again.
Also, good quality MIP solvers make use of cutting planes,node presolving and other techniques to narrow down the solution space. By relaxing the constraints into the objective function, you remove some (many?) of those tools.
